# Find matches between two arrays, AND the first array == 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays (y_true and y_pred), both consisting of 0's and 1's of the same length.

I want a more efficient/faster way of counting how many times y_pred == y_true, AND when y_pred == 1. I'm not interested in counting the matching 0's.

Right now, my function looks like this using a for loop:

```
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer
# Make a custom metric function
def my_custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):       # Bring in the arrays
    good_matches = 0                          # Set counter to 0
    for num, i in enumerate(y_pred):          # for each y_pred in array...
        if i == y_true[num] & i == 1:         # if y_pred == y_true AND y_pred == 1...
            good_matches += 1                 # count it as a good match
    return float(good_matches / sum(y_true))  # return good matches as a % of all the 1's in y_true
```

....it works, but the for loop is slow and not very efficient. I was hoping to utilize something like this:

```
# Make a custom metric function
def my_custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return float(sum(y_pred == y_true)) / sum(y_true)
```

...simple, but I don't know how to add in the "& y_pred == 1" part. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arrays aren't already boolean, make them boolean. This can be done cheaply with a view, or more simply with `astype`:

```
y_pred = y_pred.astype(bool)
y_true = y_true.astype(bool)
```

This step can be omitted if the arrays are already boolean, or if they really will never contain anything but zeros and ones.

Now `good_matches` is just

```
good_matches = np.sum(y_pred & y_true)
```

To see why that's so, note that in addition to obviously containing `y_pred == y_true`, the expression can only be true when `y_pred` is true, so it automatically implies `y_pref == 1` and `y_true == 1`, by the definition of the `&` operator.

Your final result is therefore

```
np.sum(y_pred & y_true) / np.sum(y_true)
```

This can be alternatively written as

```
np.count_nonzero(y_pred & y_true) / np.count_nonzero(y_true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to check the lists against each other while filtering out y_pred == 0, then get your accuracy by dividing the matches by the length of the compare list.

```py
compare = [p == t for p, t in zip(y_pred, y_true) if p == 1]
accuracy = compare.count(True) / len(compare)
```

Or for something utilizing numpy:

```
mask = np.where(y_true == y_pred)
matches = y_pred[mask]
accuracy = np.sum(matches) / len(matches)
```